# What is the easiest way to make a website responsive?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am a beginner and I've created some of my website already, but I realized that it wouldn't be visible well in all devices and screen sizes. I am willing to restart on my website, and implement this responsive framework, but I don't know where to get started, how to get started, which framework to use, or anything about creating a responsive website. I've looked into Bootstrap, but I saw that you had to go with the navigation bar that they provide, and I don't want that. I want to create my whole website customized by me. I've seen some websites, where when you are on your phone, it automatically goes to something like m.facebook.com, what is their method of doing that? Are they rewriting their whole entire code for each resolution? Please help!

Comment: If you use Bootstrap you don't have to use their navigation, just find another or create your own. You could just use Bootstrap for the grid layout. If you want to do it all yourself take a look at css media queries

Comment: @Maxxi If I use bootstrap for the grid layout, and make my website custom build, would it still turn out well on all other screen sizes?

Comment: The Bootstrap components are mobile responsive, but it depends what you do with them. You'll need to look into css media queries for your "custom" bits

Comment: You can completely build your own responsive navbar from scratch, but for most purposes I imagine you could just retheme their navbar and come up with something satisfactory to your needs. For example, check out [these themes](http://bootswatch.com/) -- they all use the stock Bootstrap navbar, but have completely customized it.

Answer (score 2):

If you DO NOT want to use bootstrap, you can use standard media queries "fluid design" instead. I created a easy to follow fiddle with some fun stuff for you to try out http://jsfiddle.net/xfobotx6/7/

remember to put `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`  in your `<head>` section of your html to make this work.

**edit** It is strongly opinion base on "what is the easiest way?" I just gave you an example of "a" way, but its up to you to decide what is easiest for you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can go with @Adam Buchanan Smith's answer if your interested in responsive design. if not, just do something like this with javascript to redirect the page like you said from facebook.com to m.facebook.com

```
if (screen.width <= 800) {
            window.location = "page.aspx";
        }
```

By doing this, you will have to do at least 2 versions (desktop & mobile) of your website. On the upside, you can fully customize it.